# firebase / object not found

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

i am developing a chat application using react and firebase and on adding firebase database i am recieving a error

Firebase Storage: Object 'mandy' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'mandy' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

This is the source code

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import Add from '../images/addAvatar.png'
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth, db, storage } from "../Firebase";
import {  ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 


const Register = () => {
  const [err, setErr] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const displayName = e.target[0].value;
    const email = e.target[1].value;
    const password = e.target[2].value;
    const file = e.target[3].files[0];

    try{ 
      const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)

      const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);
      console.log("Storage Reference:", storageRef.toString()); 

      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

      // Register three observers:
      
      uploadTask.on(
        (error) => {
          setErr(true)
        }, 
        () => {

          getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then( async (downloadURL) => {
            await updateProfile(res.user,{
              displayName,
              photoURL:downloadURL,
            });
            await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid),{
              uid: res.user.uid,
              displayName,
              email,
              photoURL: downloadURL,
            }); 
          });
        }
      );


    }catch(err){
      setErr(true)
    }
      
  }



  return (
    <div className='formContainer' >
      <div className="formWrapper">
        <span className="logo">Real Chat</span>
        <span className="title">Register</span>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
          <input type="text" placeholder='Name' />
          <input type="email" placeholder='Email' />
          <input type="password" placeholder='Password' />
          <input style={{display:'none'}}   type="file" id='file' />
          <label htmlFor="file"> <img src={Add} alt="" /> <span>Add an avatar</span> </label>
          <button>Sign up</button>
          {err && <span>Something went wrong</span> }
        </form>
        <p>Already have account ? Login</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Register
```

i have tried to put updateProfile and setDoc in try and catch still not working
i have changed the firebase database rule to true and still not working

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the Firebase documentation on [monitoring upload progress](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#monitor_upload_progress), the `snapshot.on` method takes **3** parameters:

1. An monitoring callback, which gets called repeatedly.
2. An error callback, which gets called in case an error occurs.
3. A completion callback, which gets called when the upload completes successfully.

You're only passing two values, so your second callback is called in case of an error (which you ignore). And since an error means that the upload failed, calling `getDownloadURL` on the reference gives another error, which you log.

---

One solution is to pass the additional/first callback as shown in the docs I linked.

If all you care about is the completion or failed of the upload however, it is easier to use the Promise of the task rather than all the callbacks:

```
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

uploadTask.then(() => {
  getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then( async (downloadURL) => {
    await updateProfile(res.user,{
      displayName,
      photoURL:downloadURL,
    });
    await setDoc(doc(db, "users", res.user.uid),{
      uid: res.user.uid,
      displayName,
      email,
      photoURL: downloadURL,
    }); 
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  setErr(true)
});
```